# !0 guaranteed to be 1 in C89?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c89

I've searched the standard but didn't notice the mentioned part.

Is it just "anything but 0" and 1 or it is compiler-dependent?

Comment: Built-in operators that yield logically Boolean results (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `&&`, `||`, `!`) always yield exactly `0` or `1`, of type `int`. Certain library functions, like `isdigit()`, return `0` for false or any non-zero value for true.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`.

Appears in C89/C90, C99, and C11.

Comment: Can you add in the link for where you found this?

Answer (score 4):

As hobbs said in his answer, [section 6.5.3.3.5 of the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) states that `!0` evaluates to `1`.

Additionally, this behavior can be used to normalize an integer to a boolean value (i.e. either `0` or `1`) with the expression `!!x`.

- When `x` = `0`, `!!x` = `!!0` = `!1` = `0`.
- When `x` != `0`, `!x` = `0`, so `!!x` = `!0` = `1`.